# How to use property in WPF XAML from codebehind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, variables

I just want to get my variable from the xaml.cs to use it into my xaml:
Here my xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Calendar
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static CultureInfo french = 
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");

        private static string nowStr =
            DateTime.Now.ToString(French);

        public static string NowStr { get => nowStr; set => nowStr = value; }
        public static CultureInfo French { get => french; set => french = value; }
        public MainWindow()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

And here my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Calendar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calendar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.425,0.522">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MainWindow.nowStr}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So, I want to get my "nowStr" to display it in my MainWindow, but I don't really understand how it works, here I am using the binding but nothing happen, I used the local: and still nothing. I am a little confused because I search answers in stack but I tryed the responses and nothing worked. 
If you can explain me how I can get my nowStr to my xaml it will be graceful.

Comment: If you are using MVVM those properties should be in the View Model and the DataContext should be set to the ViewModel. As it is now you have properties of with values but the DataContext of your window is not bound to where they are

Comment: This is a bit broad. You've got several problems, you have not setted the DataContext, you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and, your variable starts with a capital `N` and in your binding starts with `n`. I think you must read a bit more about WPF and MVVM

Comment: Yes it's strange about N and n, but I didn't wrote it myself I used "alt" + "enter" and visual studio suggested the lines to me. So I have to bound my DataContext with my ViewModel

Comment: @Lithium No where has OP indicated he is using MVVM

Comment: @Kravennagen `alt+enter` do you use `Resharper`? Not everything Resharper suggests is right. So please use with care

Comment: @MickyD OP is not mentioning `MVVM` but he is using `Binding` so you could suggest that he wants to use `MVVM`

Comment: @JordyvanEijk There is zero rule that WPF apps must use MVVM if binding is desired,  It is perfectly acceptable for XAML to bind directly to properties in a window's code behind if that window is the datacontext.  Actually as I write this, I just realised you are the author of the answer below of which I upvoted as it is clear you are aware already of what I am saying :)

Comment: @MickyD you are right. But i was just suggesting reading about MVVM, not assuming OP was using it :)

Comment: @Pikoh fair point my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of you .cs file add `DataContext = this;`
Now in your TextBlock use `Text="{Binding NowStr}"`

And implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `MainWindow` class and in the setter of your property cal notify

And why are you creating static properties?

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly ! For the static I have errors when I delete them so I keep it